# Use one-to-one MySQL Relation or not?

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-one

I have **user** table, and I need to expand it with **author** and **partner** data. Should I put additional columns in same table or create 2 more tables (**user_author** and **user_partner**) with **one-to-one** relationship ?

*Tables and columns are simplified for example.*

**user**

```
id
name
email
password
avatar
is_active
```

**user_author**

```
user_id => user.id (PK, UNQ)
description
amount_per_text
max_text
is_active
```

**user_partner**

```
user_id => user.id (PK, UNQ)
name
description
image_logo
is_active
```

User cannot be both author and partner. And then I can have classes like **User.php** for normal users, **UserPartner.php** and **UserAuthor.php** which extends **User.php** class.

Does it make sense or should I just put those columns in **user** table ?

Comment: It's ok in this way, just add one more field `type` to the user table, to determinate, is that user an author or partner. `is_acitve` is unnecessary in the other two tables, because `user` table  store this information. `description` can be in `user` table also.

Comment: Its better to maintain diff tables instead of putting all data in single table.

Comment: In general, refer to @HannoBinder's answer below. But looking to your fields; do the `is_active` columns have another meaning in the `author`/`partner` table then in the `user` table? You (should) _must_ avoid putting flags/values in different places which have the same meaning. (the same applies to the `description` field btw)

Comment: In main **user** table will put **is_author** and **is_partner** fields (or just one field - **type**) so I could quickly find out if user is author, partner or just normal user.

@giorgio description field will put in **user** table, **is_active** field tells if user has been activated his account, and in partner/author tells if user is still author or partner. Author can write for 1 year for me and then stops writing so I need to know if he is still the author or not.

Comment: @fsasvari sounds like well-thought design. I don't want to be a nitpick, just saying: as a rule of the thumb you should try to name fields (and variables in general) so that anyone who reads it, and has never wrote a line of code in your app, immediately knows what is the meaning. In your case for example, `is_activated` for the `user` table, and `is_active` for the `author`/`partner` table would seem more clear to me. Yet again; excuse me for being such a nitpick ;)

Comment: @giorgio no problem, I'm alwalys open for discussion and learning and your comment about **is_active/is_activated** is in place ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are valid and frequently used.

The normalization theory of a relational schema would not allow to put all the data in a single table for reasons of data consistency. This would favor a multi-table approach.

In the single-table approach you'll end up with a lot of empty (null) fields in every record in the table.

When using multiple tables, however, you may have to perform one or two joins just to find out if a record is a partner or an author. Hence, from a performance viewpoint, the single-table solution is preferrable.

In both cases, you could include an extra field, e.g. "recordType", in user to quickly and easily discriminate between the different types of records. This will give the best possible runtime performance.

Comment: Thanks for answer, will use one-to-one approach with some alternations from your, and other users answers.